# Issue with sequelize nested query - Sub query returns array object

Tags: nested, subquery, sequelize.js

```
const pEntries = await DB.models.pcPhoto.findAll({
    raw : true,
    attributes : ['filename'],
    where: {
        eid : { $in: await DB.models.entrySettings.findAll({
            attributes : ['id'],
            raw: true,
            where: {
                emplId : '99999'
            } 
        }) 
    }
}
});
```

I get the following result from the subquery
**`[ {id: 801},{id: 802},.....{id:900} ]`**

While executing the query the error is

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value { id: 968 }

How to handle this and get the only array of values so that the query is executed smoothly.

Comment: Do you have any relation b/w entrySettings and pcPhoto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const settings = await DB.models.entrySettings.findAll({
  attributes: ['id'],
  raw: true,
  where: { emplId : '99999' }
})

const eIds = settings.map(el => el.id)

const pEntries = await DB.models.pcPhoto.findAll({
  raw : true,
  attributes : ['filename'],
  where: {eid: {
    $in: eIds
  }}
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it in a single query?

Comment: @Prathyusha you can use $in: (await  DB.models.entrySettings.findAll(...).map(el => el.id)) to make it looks like a single query. However it is two query.  To use real one query, you should use association and join query, have a look at Vivek Doshi 's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in single query , without using sub-query , but for that you need to define proper **[association](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)** b/w model like , **and that's a good way to go**

```
pcPhoto.hasMany(entrySettings , { foreignKey: 'eid' });
```

And then just run :

```
DB.models.pcPhoto.findAll({
    raw : true,
    attributes : [ 'id' , 'filename' , 'eid' ],
    include : {
        model : DB.models.entrySettings ,
        where : { emplId : '99999' } 
    }
});
```